# how can i use cscope to find task_struct at linux kernel

Tags: kernel, cscope

i'm studying about os
especially linux kernel

i'll tell my situation.

i downloaded linux kernel at kernel.org and get some tools like ctags, cscope and add some plugin at vimrc
and i think, i compiled kernel too. there are linux-header.deb and linux-image.deb at the folder, and did something to cscope.
so i got cscope.out and i know command cscope -d

and now, my question is
what can i do with cscope-d?

i need to find task_struct and thread_struct, and
what's the variable of thread_struct type in task_struct

i dont know what can i do with cscope.
there are 'find c symbol', 'global definition', 'text string' etc

when i typed task_struct at 'find this c symbol' 
there are lots of header files.
whe i typed task_struct at 'global defition' 
there are lots too
1)what's the difference with that two?

and when i entered a header, there's just a statement with out detail of struct.
2)something i missed? or i need to check all of header files?

it was long, but questions are 1) and 2)
i need ur help:(

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at some existing articles or posts like [here](https://www.embeddedarm.com/blog/tag-jumping-in-a-codebase-using-ctags-and-cscope-in-vim/), [here](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse451/12sp/tutorials/tutorial_cscope.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828157/how-to-use-cscope).

I have not used cscope but I tend to recommend generating tags especially since for kernel you can generate tags by simply invoking "make tags" from the root of the kernel source directory. For jumping to a definition, you can then do Ctrl + [. You can see the rest of bindings [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags). Note that to be more specific this is ctags and works without any special settings for vim.

To answer your question on "lots of header files". task_struct is defined in [lockdep.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/tools/include/linux/lockdep.h#L26) or [sched.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched.h#L592) and have different fields and information depending on that context. The rest of instances that you see, for example like in arch/ directories tend to be forward declarations. For an understanding of task_struct, you might want to have a look at [this](https://notes.shichao.io/lkd/ch3/).

For forward declaration, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration).